# Add onto data in table instead of replace

Tags: sequelize.js

Is there a sequelize query command that will insert data into the table without writing over whats already there. All the sequelize queries replace any information in the column they dont add onto it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.